# Using vector for buckets in boost intrusive

Tags: c++, boost, g++, c++17, boost-intrusive

How does one manage the buckets of `boost::intrusive::unordered_set` with `std::vector`? The following code gives me nightmares:

```
#include <boost/intrusive/unordered_set.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

namespace BI = boost::intrusive;

struct ValuableData : public BI::unordered_set_base_hook<>
{
    int  x;
    int  y;
    char c;
};

typedef BI::base_hook<BI::unordered_set_base_hook<>> Options;
typedef BI::unordered_bucket<Options>::type     BucketType;
typedef BI::unordered_bucket_ptr<Options>::type BucketPtr;

struct VectorTraits{

    std::vector<BucketType> v;

    BucketPtr bucket_begin(){
        return v.data();
    }

    uint32_t bucket_count() const {
        return v.capacity();
    }
};

struct dumhash{
    uint32_t operator()(const ValuableData &data) const {
        return data.x;
    }
};

struct dumcomp{
    bool operator()(const ValuableData &data, const ValuableData &datb)     const {
    return true;
}
};

typedef BI::unordered_set<ValuableData, 
        BI::hash<dumhash>, 
        BI::equal<dumcomp>,
        BI::bucket_traits<VectorTraits>> MySet;

int main(){

    VectorTraits tr;

    tr.v.reserve(100);
    tr.v.push_back(BucketType()); //.data() may return null is vector is empty.

    MySet set(tr);
    set.rehash(tr);

    return 0;
}
```

The error message indicates a violation of `const` qualifiers. my `boost` version is 1.73.0, my compiler g++ 10.2.0. I must used `c++17`.

The boost intrusive manual mentions the `const_bucket_ptr` but does not indicate how to reach to that type. I suspect this is the source of my bug, see:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/intrusive/unordered_set_unordered_multiset.html#intrusive.unordered_set_unordered_multiset.custom_bucket_traits

EDIT: I replaced the previous code I was actually using with a simpler example you can fully compile at home. Here is my full error message:

```
In file included from include/boost/intrusive/unordered_set.hpp:18,
                 from src/BoostIntrusiveSet.cpp:9:
include/boost/intrusive/hashtable.hpp: In instantiation of 'void boost::intrusive::hashtable_impl<ValueTraits, VoidOrKeyOfValue, VoidOrKeyHash, VoidOrKeyEqual, BucketTraits, SizeType, BoolFlags>::rehash_impl(const bucket_traits&, bool) [with ValueTraits = boost::intrusive::bhtraits<ValuableData, boost::intrusive::slist_node_traits<void*>, boost::intrusive::safe_link, boost::intrusive::dft_tag, 4>; VoidOrKeyOfValue = void; VoidOrKeyHash = dumhash; VoidOrKeyEqual = dumcomp; BucketTraits = VectorTraits; SizeType = long long unsigned int; long long unsigned int BoolFlags = 3; boost::intrusive::hashtable_impl<ValueTraits, VoidOrKeyOfValue, VoidOrKeyHash, VoidOrKeyEqual, BucketTraits, SizeType, BoolFlags>::bucket_traits = VectorTraits]':
include/boost/intrusive/hashtable.hpp:2944:13:   required from 'void boost::intrusive::hashtable_impl<ValueTraits, VoidOrKeyOfValue, VoidOrKeyHash, VoidOrKeyEqual, BucketTraits, SizeType, BoolFlags>::rehash(const bucket_traits&) [with ValueTraits = boost::intrusive::bhtraits<ValuableData, boost::intrusive::slist_node_traits<void*>, boost::intrusive::safe_link, boost::intrusive::dft_tag, 4>; VoidOrKeyOfValue = void; VoidOrKeyHash = dumhash; VoidOrKeyEqual = dumcomp; BucketTraits = VectorTraits; SizeType = long long unsigned int; long long unsigned int BoolFlags = 3; boost::intrusive::hashtable_impl<ValueTraits, VoidOrKeyOfValue, VoidOrKeyHash, VoidOrKeyEqual, BucketTraits, SizeType, BoolFlags>::bucket_traits = VectorTraits]'
src/BoostIntrusiveSet.cpp:64:15:   required from here
include/boost/intrusive/hashtable.hpp:3153:73: error: passing 'const bucket_traits' {aka 'const VectorTraits'} as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
 3153 |       const bucket_ptr new_buckets      = new_bucket_traits.bucket_begin();
      |                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

Comment: PS. Note that your `dumcomp` invokes UB because the requirements for the equality is that it corresponds to the hash function. (I fixed it for my answer)

Comment: Why does that mean exactly ? (keep in mind that the current one is a placeholder to make the example compile).

Comment: It means that the algorithms have [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) if the hash/equality donot match.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/intrusive/unordered_set_unordered_multiset.html#intrusive.unordered_set_unordered_multiset.custom_bucket_traits) states that a const overload for `bucket_begin()` is required:

> A user-defined bucket-traits must fulfill the following interface:
>
> ```
> class my_bucket_traits
> {
>    bucket_ptr        bucket_begin();
>    const_bucket_ptr  bucket_begin() const;
>    std::size_t bucket_count() const;
> };
> ```

I'm not sure why you think you can safely make the bucket traits own a bucket container. What the example does is store a **pointer** to the bucket. This solves the issues:

- the bucket traits is cheaply copyable
- the lifetime of the bucket is not tied to a copy of the traits (because the ownership is not held)
- the bucket data is naturally not const even if the trait instance is

### Fixing

Applying the same approach here:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4abe05a08bd04353)**

```
#include <boost/intrusive/unordered_set.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

namespace BI = boost::intrusive;
struct ValuableData : public BI::unordered_set_base_hook<> {
    int  x = 0;
    int  y = 0;
    char c = 0;
};

using Options    = BI::base_hook<BI::unordered_set_base_hook<> >;
using BucketType = BI::unordered_bucket<Options>::type;
using BucketPtr  = BI::unordered_bucket_ptr<Options>::type;

struct VectorTraits {
    std::vector<BucketType>* v;
    BucketPtr bucket_begin() const { return v->data(); }
    [[nodiscard]] uint32_t bucket_count() const { return v->capacity(); }
};

struct dumhash {
    uint32_t operator()(const ValuableData& data) const { return data.x; }
};

struct dumcomp {
    bool operator()(const ValuableData& data, const ValuableData& datb) const {
        return data.x == datb.x;
    }
};
typedef BI::unordered_set<ValuableData, BI::hash<dumhash>, BI::equal<dumcomp>,
                          BI::bucket_traits<VectorTraits>>
    MySet;

int main() {
    std::vector<BucketType> buckets(13);
    VectorTraits tr { &buckets };

    MySet set(tr);
    set.rehash(tr);

    std::cout << buckets.size() << "\n";
    buckets.resize(57);
    set.rehash(tr);

    std::cout << buckets.size() << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
13
57
```

Comment: How can we obtain the type labeled 'const_bucket_ptr ' ?

Comment: @etienneparmentier Looks like that might be a documentation oversight: it may have existed before, but might also be copied from a section about a non-pointer type. In practice, all pointers can be trivially const without changing the pointed-to-type (and mutation comes courtesy of copyability)